# What is the best way to form inner products?

Tags: julia

I was delighted to learn that Julia allows a beautifully succinct way to form inner products:

```
julia> x = [1;0]; y = [0;1];

julia> x'y
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
0
```

This alternative to `dot(x,y)` is nice, but it can lead to surprises:

```
julia> @printf "Inner product = %f\n" x'y
Inner product = ERROR: type: non-boolean (Array{Bool,1}) used in boolean context

julia> @printf "Inner product = %f\n" dot(x,y)
Inner product = 0.000000
```

So while i'd like to write `x'y`, it seems best to avoid it, since otherwise I need to be conscious of pitfalls related to scalars versus 1-by-1 matrices.

But I'm new to Julia, and probably I'm not thinking in the right way. Do others use this succinct alternative to `dot`, and if so, when is it safe to do so?

Comment: It is not very clear what you need (or don't) and what are you willing to sacrifice, so I'm not posting an answer:

You can use the [`⋅` operator](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/#Base.⋅) instead of `dot`. You can also [declare](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#type-declarations) what type you expect for a variable/returning function: `x=[0;1]::Array{Float64,1}`

Answer (score 12):

There is a conceptual problem here. When you do

```
julia> x = [1;0]; y = [0;1];
julia> x'y
0
```

That is actually turned into a matrix * vector product with dimensions of 2x1 and 1 respectively, resulting in a 1x1 matrix. Other languages, such as MATLAB, don't distinguish between a 1x1 matrix and a scalar quantity, but Julia does for a variety of reasons. It is thus never safe to use it as alternative to the "true" inner product function `dot`, which is defined to return a scalar output.

Now, if you aren't a fan of the `dot`s, you can consider `sum(x.*y)` of `sum(x'y)`. Also keep in mind that column and row vectors are different: in fact, there is no such thing as a row vector in Julia, more that there is a 1xN matrix. So you get things like

```
julia> x = [ 1 2 3 ]
1x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3

julia> y = [ 3 2 1]
1x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  2  1

julia> dot(x,y)
ERROR: `dot` has no method matching dot(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,2})

You might have used a 2d row vector where a 1d column vector was required.
Note the difference between 1d column vector [1,2,3] and 2d row vector [1 2 3].
You can convert to a column vector with the vec() function.
```

The error message suggestion is `dot(vec(x),vec(y)`, but `sum(x.*y)` also works in this case and is shorter.

```
julia> sum(x.*y)
10

julia> dot(vec(x),vec(y))
10
```

Comment: `dot( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] )` now works on nightly build.

Comment: `sum(x.*y)` is the way to do it if `x·y` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Now, you can write `x⋅y` instead of `dot(x,y)`.
To write the `⋅` symbol, type `\cdot` followed by the `TAB` key.
If the first argument is complex, it is conjugated.
Now, `dot()` and `⋅` also work for matrices.
Since version 1.0, you need

> using LinearAlgebra

before you use the dot product function or operator.